# C# Amazon Product Advertising API

Tags: c#, soap, amazon-product-api

As of August 15, Amazon made it compulsory to sign all requests made to their Product Advertising API. I thought I had got everything working just fine but when the 15th finally came around, my web application stopped working and pretty much ever since I have been trying to find out how to sign the SOAP requests.

Amazon has an outdated sample code for signing requests that doesn't appear to work [here](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=2481&categoryID=14)

Basically, I need to know how to add a signature to the my requests using the most current C# SOAP API and .NET 3.5.

I hope I have given enough details, if I haven't please feel free to ask me to elaborate.

Thank You
The_Lorax

**UPDATE:**
I am using MVC and need to know how to add the Signature to the the ItemLookup or AWSECommerceService object. Is there an attribute that contains the signature value? How does it get attached to the request?

On [this page](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/index.html?NotUsingWSSecurity.html), they say that I must include the Signature and TimeStamp parameters but the intellisense does now show any such attributes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check out http://flyingpies.wordpress.com/2009/08/01/17/. It has a walkthrough and a sample visual studio solution using C#, SOAP, WCF on .NET 3.5.

Comment: I saw this article a while ago and it would work for WCF but I am using MVC and I am using "AWSECommerceService" instead of"AWSECommerceServicePortTypeClient".

Comment: I ended up using a modified version of this code and a Service Reference instead of a WebReference. Thanks for you help, it is must appreciated

Comment: +1 from me. I didn't have this issue but this is the same code that I am using for my basis to call the Amazon product advertising API.

Comment: I'd vote this up twice if I could. Thanks for pointing to the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

This library automatic sign the requests (Install-Package Nager.AmazonProductAdvertising)
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nager.AmazonProductAdvertising/

Example:

```cs
var authentication = new AmazonAuthentication("accesskey", "secretkey");
var client = new AmazonProductAdvertisingClient(authentication, AmazonEndpoint.US);
var result = await client.SearchItemsAsync("canon eos");
```